# Results on compact slices in a regular foliation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, foliations

Let $(M,\mathcal{F}$) be a smooth and regular foliation (not necessarily of comdimension 1). I am wondering if there are known (partial) results on the existence of compact, connected submanifolds $F\subseteq M$ with $\dim(F)>0$ such that $T_bF\cap T_b\mathcal{F}=\{0\}$?

For instance, this is possible on the torus, foliated by circles, since we can just take a circle perpendicular to the leaves, but it is not possible on $\mathbb{R}^2$, foliated by horizontal lines. However, the same foliation by 1-dimensional lines on $\mathbb{R}^3$ admits such a compact slice. However, this fails again if $\mathbb{R}^3$ is foliated by two-dimensional horizontal planes.

Comment: Do you want to impose some condition on the dimension of $F$? If not, you can just take $F = \{b\}$.

Comment: Yes I want $F$ to be compact, connected and of dimension $>0$